# Is transmuting (T, ()) to T safe?

Tags: rust, tuples, data-representation, transmute

I am implementing an alternative to a `BTreeMap<K, V>`. On top of this I'm building a BTreeSet, which is a wrapper around `type MyBTreeSetContents<T> = MyBTreeMap<T, ()>`.

Internally, leaf nodes of this BTree contain a `Vec<(K, V)>` of values.
In the case of the BTreeSet, this thus becomes a `Vec<(K, ())>`.

I want to provide a fast iterator over references of the values in the BTreeSet. An iterator that produces `&T`. But the best I can get so far without reaching for transmute is an iterator that produces `&(T, ())`.

So therefore the question:

- Is the memory representation of `K`, `(K, )` and `(K, ())` the same?
- Is it therefore OK to transmute between `(K, ())` and `K`?
- And by extension, is it OK to transmute the `Vec<(K, ())>` to a `Vec<K>`?

If there are alternative approaches that circumvent usage of `std::mem::transmute` all-together, those would of course also be very much appreciated!

Comment: I am mystified as to why you'd need `transmute` for writing this iterator. That seems like a question in itself ("How to write an efficient iterator for a set implemented in terms of a map?").

Comment: What's the problem with just `map`ping the iterator over vector with something like `|pair| &pair.0`?

Comment: @HTNW I added the extra information here to give some context and make sure I did not fall into the [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). That said, you are right that asking for help with that original problem very well might make sense as a separate question.

Comment: @Cerberus That indeed might be an appropriate alternative approach, that is much simpler! I'll have to check what happens in practice w.r.t. what the iterators compile down to. It might be the case that `vec().iter().map()` misses certain optimizations that `transmute(vec).iter()` would have. But it definitely seems like a safer and cleaner option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** As far as what is currently enforced, transmuting `(T, ())` to `T` is not guaranteed. Tuples use the default representation which does not imply anything about the layout beyond what is said in [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html?highlight=layout#the-default-representation). Only `#[repr(transparent)]` will guarantee layout compatibility.

---

However, it will probably work and may eventually be guaranteed. From [Structs and Tuples](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/structs-and-tuples.html) in the Unsafe Code Guidelines:

> In general, an anonymous tuple type `(T1..Tn)` of arity N is laid out "as if" there were a corresponding tuple struct...
>
> ...
>
> For the purposes of struct layout 1-ZST<sup>[1]</sup> fields are ignored.
>
> In particular, if all but one field are 1-ZST, then the struct is equivalent to a single-field struct. In other words, if all but one field is a 1-ZST, then the entire struct has the same layout as that one field.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> type Zst1 = ();
> struct S1(i32, Zst1); // same layout as i32
> ```
>
> <sup>[1] Types with zero size are called zero-sized types, which is abbreviated as "ZST". This document also uses the "1-ZST" abbreviation, which stands for "one-aligned zero-sized type", to refer to zero-sized types with an alignment requirement of 1.</sup>

If my understanding of this is correct, `(K, ())` has the equivalent layout to `K` and thus can be transmuted safely. However, that will not extend to transmuting `Vec<T>` to `Vec<U>` as mentioned in [Transmutes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html) from the Rustonomicon:

> Even different instances of the same generic type can have wildly different layout. `Vec<i32>` and `Vec<u32>` *might* have their fields in the same order, or they might not.

Unfortunately, you should take this with a grain of salt. The Unsafe Code Guidelines is an effort to recommend what `unsafe` code can rely on, but currently it only advertises itself as a work-in-progress and that any concrete additions to the language specification will be moved to the official Rust Reference. I say this "will probably work" because a facet of the guidelines is to document current behavior. But as of yet, no guarantee like this has been mentioned in the reference.